# Open browser with Data URI Scheme instead of a URL

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, uri, url-scheme

Well, I was breaking the hell of my brain cells with this and no solution came up...

Usually, in Android, to open the Web Browser in a specified Website, we do this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

So, I got a Data URI Scheme (dunno if it is written this way, i'm not an expert on this kind of stuff) like this:

```
data:text/html;charset=utf8;base64,<base64 html code>
```

If I copy and paste this in a web browser, it will handle it the way I want it.

But how can I do it programatically in Android?

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(dataHTMLBase64));
 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

dataHTMLBase64 stores the Data URI Scheme I mentioned before.

The code above won't work. It won't even launch chrome.

What can I do?

PS: I'm not good with English. Please warn me if I didn't express myself the right way...

Comment: I would be surprised if browsers generally support that `Uri` scheme, for incoming `Intents`, anyway. They'll handle it internally, when they encounter URLs like that from Web pages that they load.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it appears that one can launch a Data URI in an Android browser quite easily.

```
String url = "data:text/html;charset=utf8,<b>Hee-haw!</b>";

startActivity(Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(
        Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER)
        .setData(Uri.parse(url.toString())));
```

---

Using [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) I reviewed the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the Google Chrome `.apk` file.
(apktool is quite easy to install, and then the command is simply `apktool d example.apk`)

I found the relevant intent filters (listed below) so there are many possible ways to launch the browser. Of course other browsers may have different intent filters, but it seems that `APP_BROWSER` is a good choice.

```
<activity-alias android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main" android:targetActivity="org.chromium.chrome.browser.document.ChromeLauncherActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="googlechrome"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="about"/>
        <data android:scheme="javascript"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="googlechrome"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="about"/>
        <data android:scheme="content"/>
        <data android:scheme="javascript"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="multipart/related" android:scheme="file"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.speech.action.VOICE_SEARCH_RESULTS"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get these data URIs from somewhere you could do two things:

1. Parse the data content out of it and use it in some `WebView`and call `loadData(...)` on it to display the contents
2. Save the data content of the URIs to some file, use `FileProvider` to make this file accessible outside of your app and use the URI returned by that to fire up a browser / view intent