# How to open html in mobile browser from qrcode?

Tags: html, mobile, uri, qr-code

I'm trying to open a webpage from a qrcode, even if the user who scanned the qrcode is offline.

To do so, the best way I found is to put the html content of the webpage in a data uri scheme, and put the result as the content of the qrcode:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic Web Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
```

becomes

`data:,<html><head><title>Basic Web Page</title></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>`

and I create a qrcode from it,
but this isn't optimal as it isn't automatically showed in the browser.

So as a summary, I would like to find a way to automatically open the browser, in order to display the html content I provide. Does someone have a lead or something?

Thanks!

Comment: where u have hosted u r html code?

Comment: @AmareshSM — Embedded in the URL, as the question said and demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

A QR code is just a means to represent a piece of text.

It is common to use it to store a URL that the user can then visit (generally after they look at it to check that it doesn't appear to be visiting a malicious site).

There is no way — at least not in the general case — to force the QR scanner software to do anything specific with the text (such as treat it as as a URL and open it in a browser).

Comment: I think there are several ways to triggers actions from the content of the qrcode.

Most of the time, qrcode scanner implement the following functions:

Displaying text,
Setting up system alerts,
Adding events to calendars,
Opening URLs in a browser,
Collecting contact information (including vCards),
Sending email,
Sending text messages (SMS),
Geolocation,
Calling other phones,
Connecting to WiFi,


These function use uri schemes

Indeed there are no standards, but something working in a majority of cases would already please me

Answer (score 0):

This *almost* works:

```
data:text/html,<html><head><title>Basic Web Page</title></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>
```

[The above as a QR-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEExw.png)

Unfortunately, at least my QR-code reader apps did not not open this in a browser by default. This may be a security thing...

But if you copy and paste that into a browser, it should work in most cases. (From the mobile browsers on my Android phone, DuckDuckGo and Chrome worked, Firefox did not.)

This was used as a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

---

Additionally, if you use non-ascii characters, you need to set charset to UTF-8:

```
data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,<html><head><title>Basic Web Page</title></head><body>Hello Motörhead!</body></html>
```

---

As a bit off-topic addition, this was the best list I could find for what special functions most QR code readers support: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents

Comment: Apparently at least Android applications, such as QR code readers, could open data URI schemes in browsers if they wanted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37448361